# How to merge different shaped netcdf4 files?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, netcdf, python-xarray, netcdf4

I am storing weather forecasts as netcdf4 files. These netcdf4 files are batched following the [google maps tiles](https://www.maptiler.com/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/) principle. This means I define a zoom level (here 6) to get the extent of each tile.
Based on that information I used the following code to slice the array:

```py
    sliced_data = data.where(
        (data[lat_coord_name] <= maxLat)
        & (data[lat_coord_name] > minLat)
        & (data[lon_coord_name] <= maxLon)
        & (data[lon_coord_name] > minLon),
        drop=True,
    )
```

Here, data is a `xarray.Dataset`. At the end of this process I have 36 tiles for a weather model covering middle europe.

My problem is to merge them back to the native untiled `xarray.Dataset`. The projection of the weather model differs from the projection of the tile maps. So at the end I have netcdf4 files with different shapes in x and y dimension. So I have no axis to align them with xarray.

The dimension of the native grid is 340x340. You can find a test dataset [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SNCpBpJrMD2RLmA1NpVSuNA7GvLDKsev/view?usp=sharing)

My expectation was:

```py
import glob
import xarray

file_list = glob.glob('test_data_stackoverflow/*')
file_list.sort()
dataset = xarray.open_mfdataset(file_list, engine="h5netcdf")
```

But this will fail due to different shaped datasets.

I am open using other tools like netcdf4, h5netcdf or cdo. But the data should not be manipulated e.g. with an interpolation to the origin grid.

Answer (score 1):

Combining datasets with the same dimension names but different dimension sizes is not possible in an Xarray Dataset. But it *is* possible in a new type of Xarray data structure, currently under development, called a DataTree. Currently DataTree lives in a separate package - https://xarray-datatree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ - but the plan is to merge it into Xarray proper soon. DataTree is used by the library [ndpyramid](https://github.com/carbonplan/ndpyramid) to store multi-scale array data, very similar to the use case you are describing.

I would explore combing your datasets into a single DataTree object. First organize your data into a dict, and then create a DataTree from the dict. You will need to decide how to encode the level of the hierarchy. The simplest is to just use an integer for each zoom level, e.g.

```py
data_dict = {level: ds for level, ds in enumerage(file_list)}
dt = DataTree.from_dict(data_dict)
```

They ndpyramid code might be a useful reference: https://github.com/carbonplan/ndpyramid/blob/main/ndpyramid/core.py

Answer (score -1):

You can probably solve this using CDO's merge method:

```
cdo merge test_data_stackoverflow/* out.nc
```

If the 36 tiles make up a 6 x 6 grid, then mergegrid can potentially merge them:

```
cdo mergegird test_data_stackoverflow/* out.nc
```

Comment: Output for merge ```cdo    merge: Open failed on >test_data_stackoverflow/harmonie_knmi_2021_03_20_18_35_23.nc<
              Unsupported file structure```

Comment: Output for mergrid: ```cdo (Abort): Unprocessed Input, could not process all Operators/Files```

Comment: cdo does not work either.